# How can I access the JPEG image pixels as a 3D array like we do in MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, jpeg

I want to process an image in C++. How can I access the 3D array representing the JPEG image as is done in MATLAB?

Comment: How could it possibly be a 3 dimensional array? Images are 2d objects...

Comment: The color channels are the third dimension.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: Ah. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using OpenCV for the task; C++ documentation is available [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/). The relevant (I believe) data structure which you'd have to use is the [Point3_ class](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#point3), which represents a 3D point in the image.

Comment: I... don't think he's looking for computer vision. Or is OpenCV a good library just for decoding JPEG?

Comment: OpenCV's a perfectly good library for decoding various image formats. I believe its cvLoadImage function is capable of opening the following image formats: BMP, DIB, JPEG, JPG, JPE, PNG, PBM, PGM, PPM, SR, RAS, TIFF, TIF.

For what it's worth, Wikipedia states that OpenCV "focuses mainly on real-time image processing."

Comment: All right, it seems OpenCV comes up with a good set of image format decoders :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've never used MATLAB for such a task, but in C++ you will need some JPEG loader library like [OpenIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) or [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/). These will allow you to access the picture as byte arrays.

FreeImage's `FreeImage_GetBits` function has a detailed example in the [documentation](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html) on how to access per pixel per channel data.

BTW, if you plan to do image processing in C/C++, I'd suggest you to check out the [Insight Segmentation and Registration Toolkit](http://www.itk.org/) and [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).